# How can I estimate the pitch of audio that I am currently recording in python?

Tags: python, pitch-detection

I believe a lot of the libraries I have looked into require loading an audio file. Is this possible to do with audio that is being recorded live? If so, what library should I use?

Comment: It's better if you specify what libraries you've already tried... Such open ended questions are usually not well taken in this community.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0):

according to the first result when i google "python audio processing"

> you can do real-time audio input/output using PyAudio. PyAudio is a wrapper around PortAudio and provides cross platform audio recording/playback in a nice, pythonic way